# What is httpd <defunct>?

Tags: http, centos, apache

```
32537 apache    16   0 87424  15m 7324 S  2.3  0.3   0:00.52 httpd              
 3302 mysql     15   0  156m  41m 4756 S  1.3  0.7  10:50.91 mysqld             
  489 apache    16   0 87016  14m 6692 S  0.7  0.2   0:00.27 httpd              
  990 apache    15   0     0    0    0 Z  0.7  0.0   0:00.12 httpd <defunct>    
  665 apache    15   0 86992  13m 5644 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.20 httpd              
32218 apache    15   0 87356  14m 6344 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.53 httpd              
    1 root      15   0  2160  640  556 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.18 init
```

From `top`, there is an occasional `httpd <defunct>` showing up. What does it do?

I found that the web server sometimes does not response to `FPDF` (print PDF at user's request). Is it related?

UPDATE, with loading information:

```
top - 11:55:59 up 17:30,  6 users,  load average: 0.53, 0.47, 0.80
Tasks: 322 total,   1 running, 320 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.1%id,  3.9%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6219412k total,  5944068k used,   275344k free,    21024k buffers
Swap:  5140792k total,       96k used,  5140696k free,  5270708k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 1951 apache    16   0     0    0    0 Z  0.9  0.0   0:00.33 httpd <defunct>    
 2267 apache    15   0 86992  13m 5876 S  0.9  0.2   0:00.22 httpd              
 3302 mysql     15   0  156m  41m 4756 S  0.9  0.7  11:43.72 mysqld             
 2220 apache    15   0 87204  14m 6496 S  0.6  0.2   0:00.28 httpd              
 2340 apache    15   0 87828  13m 5588 S  0.6  0.2   0:00.22 httpd              
 2341 apache    17   0 88236  14m 5564 S  0.6  0.2   0:00.15 httpd              
  842 apache    16   0 87432  15m 7180 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.81 httpd              
 2225 apache    18   0 88236  14m 5560 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.17 httpd              
 2401 apache    15   0 86916  12m 5344 S  0.3  0.2   0:00.11 httpd              
    1 root      24   0  2160  640  556 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.18 init
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A defunct process is a process that has exited but whose parent has not yet waited on it to read its exit status, leaving an entry in the process table.  Also known as a zombie process.  See the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) for more information.

Comment: If these processes are taking too much memory space, can I kill these without any effect on other processes?

Comment: @diggy defunct processes have already exited so you can't kill them. I would think that it would have already or will quickly release it's resources.

Answer (score 3):

A defunct process is typically one which has finished but the OS keeps it around until the parent `waits` for it to "collect" its status. You only normally see lots of this when you've written your own "forky" code and have bugs.

If you use

```
ps -Hwfe
```

You will get to see the process hierarchy and so what the parent is. Weird that it's an `httpd` process, it's normally pretty good at collecting its children. Unless your system is flat out, which is why you're using `top` in the first place...

Comment: The CPU is pretty idle (see UPDATE part of the question). The main complains from user (browser) point of view is PDF creation failed occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

When a process dies on Unix, it sends an exit code to its parent.  A defunct process, or "zombie", is one whose parent hasn't yet looked at the zombie's exit code.  Once the parent gets the exit code (using the `wait` system call), the zombie will disappear.